# Spring MockMvc and @AutoConfigureMockMvc() set headers in request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot and have Spring Security setup to use token authorization.  I have my test is setup like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {
})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc()
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
})
public class ApplicationTests {
@Test
        public void shouldReturnRepositoryIndex() throws Exception {

            mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(
                    jsonPath("$._links.people").exists());
        }
}
```

I need `get("/")` to send a header "X-AUTH: SOMETOKEN"

How do I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`.header("X-AUTH" , "SOMETOKEN")` should work.

Here is the modified mockMvc code:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/").header("X-AUTH" , "SOMETOKEN")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(
            jsonPath("$._links.people").exists());
```

The output is:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
  HTTP Method = GET
  Request URI = /
   Parameters = {}
      Headers = {X-AUTH=[SOMETOKEN]}
```

Comment: Thanks - not sure why they don't name that `addHeader` or `setHeader`

Comment: It's because when invoking `get` / `post` / `put` / `patch` ... methods, all of them are part of `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder`, so it's in a _builder-pattern_ style.